# How to trace a image to vector with pixel by pixel?

Tags: flash, bitmap, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I wan to trace a button image to vector use in Flash.
but I use the `trace bitmap` tool,it will be wrong color when the pixel color with alpha.

I try to use Illustrator to do that,but Illustrator can not trace every pixel,I want to when after trace,it look like same as the bitmap when zoom 100%

have another tools to do that?

[image: capture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Illustrator for this purpose.
Just trace with different options.
Just right to "Live Trace", you have drop down menu, use "Photo High Fidelity" at start and if this doesn't work then go for "Tracing Option". This will work for sure.

Comment: Illustrator can not trace pixel by pixel,"Photo High Fidelity" same